# How to get [NSScreen backingScaleFactor] on Cocoa targeting 10.6

Tags: macos, cocoa, xcode4

I get this code from Googling but XCode display error: "Property 'backingScaleFactor' not found on object type 'NSScreen *'"

```
CGFloat displayScale = 1.0f;
if ([[NSScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(backingScaleFactor)]) 
{

       displayScale = [NSScreen mainScreen].backingScaleFactor;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[[NSScreen mainScreen] backingScaleFactor]` and make sure that you are building for the OS X 10.7 SDK, with the deployment target set to 10.6.

Comment: -1 This isn't true. If you  use API that only exist on 10.7, then there is no build warning, but the app will crash at launch on 10.6. See here:  http://lapcatsoftware.com/articles/sdkvsdeploymenttarget.html

Comment: @Sanich: He has an explicit `[[NSScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(backingScaleFactor)]` check in there that will prevent the app from crashing because the code simply won't be executed on 10.6. Please reconsider your -1.

Comment: Yes, his code wan't crash but, your answer is still not correct. It won't help changing to SDK 10.7 to get `backingScaleFactor` property when your deployment target is 10.6

Answer (score -1):

You **can't** because `backingScaleFactor` property is available in OS X v10.7 and later. See [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSScreen_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSScreen/backingScaleFactor).
Changing to SDK 10.7 (or higher) won't help too. Because if you use API that only exist on 10.7, then there will be no build warning, but the app will crash at launch on 10.6. See [here](http://lapcatsoftware.com/articles/sdkvsdeploymenttarget.html).

**EDIT:** You can use `if ([[NSScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(backingScaleFactor)])` and your app won't crash but this is another practice for another things, and defiantly won't achieve what you are trying to.

If you describe what exactly you are trying to do and why you need the `backingScaleFactor` I'll try to help you with some tricks and hacks.

Comment: The app will not crash if `if ([[NSScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(backingScaleFactor)])` is kept.

Comment: @MrMage The question is not whether the app will crash or not.. His question is **How to get [NSScreen backingScaleFactor] on Cocoa targeting 10.6**. And the answer is that you just **can't!**. You can use the `selector check` that the program won't crash but this is not the advised practice in this case because it will compile and run but will not do what he wanted. So you answer doesn't answer his question and misleading. Please be professional and reconsider your -1.